# What does ModuleNotFoundErrorDer do

Tags: python

What is wrong with the code when I get by python pyttsx3 a ModuleNotFoundErrorDer error.

Here is my code: `import pyttsx3 engine  = pyttsx3.init() engine.say("hello") engine.runAndWait()`

I am coding with Python 3.9

Answer (score 0):

did you do `pip install pyttsx3`?

the pyttsx3 library is probaly not installed.

Comment: yes I did it but thank you for the answer